# Change left margin in a console app C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, console-application

I have a console app and I already changed the  `Console.Out.NewLine = "\r\n\r\n";` but now I would like to change the left margin, the cursor position in all my app just one time, ´cause I repeat `Console.SetCursorPosition` many times. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: You might also like to take a look at the log4net project, although that might be overkill for what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use use `\t` for left margin, you can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) more escape character in c#.

```
Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t text with left margin");
```

Comment: This would require OP to change *every* logging statement. I think Lindsay wanted to change the left margin globally with a single method call. (But then this *has* been accepted as the answer, so who knows?)